# UNIX timestamp on MySQL and MSSQL Server

Tags: mysql, t-sql, timezone, timestamp

How come there is a difference on timestamps in mysql and MS SQL Server
MySQL:

```
select now() result: 2013-07-16 08:49:26.0
```

SQL Server:

```
select getdate() result: 2013-07-16 08:48:16.47
```

and when I try to get `unix_timestamp`
MySQL:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-07-01') result: 1372629600
```

SQL Server:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND,'1970-01-01', '2013-07-01') result 1372636800
```

**problem:** there is a difference of 7200 seconds (2h) 
Is this a Time Zone problem, server time on both servers are the same as seen on `now()` and `getdate()`?

Comment: Are you in the +2h timezone ?

Comment: UTC+01:00
Central European Time

Comment: Then that's probably it, plus DST.

Comment: MySQL `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` gives seconds since the UNIX epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC).  SQL Server `DATEDIFF()` is operating on literals given in the session's timezone, which has a UTC offset of one hour plus the daylight savings adjustment which occurs between the operand dates of January and July.

Comment: Oh thanks both, @Bart Friederichs and @eggyal, so is there a way to modify `DATEDIFF()` to get UTC timestamp, same as `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`?

Comment: I concur with eggyal. Just to clarify, MySQL is interpreting that date literal using the timezone of the session (SHOW VARIABLE LIKE '%timezone%') and basically converting that to equivalent DATETIME in UTC, and then getting the difference in seconds between that and the beginning of the epoch (Jan 1, 1970 midnight UTC). SQL Server is computing the difference using the SQL Server timezone settin. Both results are "correct", according to the specification each adheres to.

Comment: On server use `GETUTCDATE()`, on client machine display date-time with timezone offset.

Comment: now only to combine `DATEDIFF()` with `GETUTCDATE()` for a specific date

Comment: I think eggyal or spencer7593 should create an answer, cause it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On SQL Server use

`select datediff(ss, '1970-01-01', SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() at time zone 'UTC')`

Here,

`SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()` returns the local system time *with the local time zone offset* enabling the conversion to UTC.  Replace it with your own `datetimeoffset` field if you want something other than the current time.

Answer (score 5):

This is quite a long solution but it seems to work. It accounts for the offset in time zones.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), '1970-01-01'), '2013-07-01')
```

Comment: This is great because you can use this for any datetime not just "now".

Answer (score 3):

You can try this link for understanding timestamp in Mysql

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-timestamp.aspx

for tsql timestamp you can check out these links

http://www.informit.com/library/content.aspx?b=STY_Sql_Server_7&seqNum=97

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188751(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late answer, but this will only work for dates NOW. If you have to analyze dates in the past and you have e.g. different time zones (summer/wintertime) this will not work properly.